# Can I get some help me in writing a SQL query for searching multiple words in a table column

Tags: sql

I am trying to write a query that searches a column of a table and returns the count with an alias name for multiple words.

```
select 
    count(STREET_ADDRESS) AS MELBOURNE 
from 
    CUSTOMERS 
where 
    STREET_ADDRESS like '%MELBOURNE%'
```

I am trying to do this for multiple cities in one query like `Melbourne, Sydney, Auckland` etc.

Comment: Provide your sample data and expected result

Comment: Like if I run the following queries together in SQL it spits out two different expected results. 

I wish to combine these two queries into one and still get the same result. 

******************************
select count(STREET_ADDRESS) AS MANGERE from CUSTOMERS where STREET_ADDRESS like '%MANGERE%'
********************************
select count(STREET_ADDRESS) AS AVONDALE from CUSTOMERS where STREET_ADDRESS like '%AVONDALE%'

Answer (score 1):

Try This,`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE STREET_ADDRESS IN ('MANGERE','AVONDALE')GROUP BY STREET_ADDRESS`

Comment: The street address column contains proper address and thus I have to use wild cards to search for keywords.

Comment: The following query works as I want it to work. 
Thanks for the help :-)
*
**********************
SELECT DISTINCT (SUM(CASE WHEN STREET_ADDRESS LIKE '%MANGERE%'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER ()) AS MANGERE_COUNT,
       (SUM(CASE WHEN STREET_ADDRESS LIKE '%AVONDALE%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER ()) AS AVONDALE_COUNT,
FROM CUSTOMERS

Comment: @Mansoor's query is the most precise & optimal one, don't confuse!

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that the number of columns in the select is fixed. Maybe i missunderstood but you want to input a list of cities and have the output contain as many columns as input's you gave?

**If not (fixed Nb cities):**
Suggestion: Add conditions to the query (to be honest, since using wildcards no really perf enhancement, you should think about adding a "city" column otherwise if the table gets too big this query will become very slow)

```
SELECT   
SUM(CASE WHEN STREET_ADDRESS LIKE '%MANGERE%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS    MANGERE_COUNT,   
SUM(CASE WHEN STREET_ADDRESS LIKE '%AVONDALE%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS AVONDALE_COUNT  
FROM CUSTOMERS  
WHERE   
STREET_ADDRESS like '%MANGERE%'  
OR  
STREET_ADDRESS like '%AVONDALE%'
```

**If that is the case:**
You will need to create dynamic SQL to transpose the output.

Hope it helps
Sérgio

Answer (score 0):

Have a derived table where you using a `case` expression returns the city name from each street_address. Then do `GROUP BY` on its result to count:

```
select count(*), city
from
(
    select case when upper(STREET_ADDRESS) like '%MELBOURNE%' then 'Melbourne'
                when upper(STREET_ADDRESS) like '%SYDNEY%' then 'Sydney'
                when upper(STREET_ADDRESS) like '%AUCKLAND%' then 'Auckland'
           end as city
    from CUSTOMERS
) dt
group by city
```

**Note**: the `UPPER()` parts aren't needed if a case insensitive collation is used.